# iterate over a vector using multiple threads (no data sharing, or vector modification)

Tags: c++, multithreading, iteration

I have a large vector of objects and I just need to iterate over the vector using multiple threads and read the objects (no modification to data or the vector). What is the most efficient method to do this? Could it be done in a lock free fashion, maybe using an atomic variable? what is most easy to read implementation of such multithreading process?

**Edit:** 
I do not want more than one thread reads the same element of vector (reading is time consuming in this case). When one thread is reading an element, I want the next thread reads the first not-yet-read element. For example when thread 1 is reading object 1, I want thread 2 reads object 2. whenever one of them is done, it can read object 3, so on and so forth.

Comment: If there's no modification, then just read the data. You only need synchronisation or atomicity if one thread modifies it while another might be accessing it.

Comment: I do not want more than one thread reads the same element of vector (reading is time consuming in this case). When one thread is reading an element, I want the next thread reads the first not-yet-read element. For example when thread 1 is reading object 1, I want thread 2 reads object 2. whenever one of them is done, it can read object 3, so on and so forth.

Comment: I assume the objects in the vector are reasonably well behaved? e.g `const` member functions are thread safe.

Comment: Can you just give each thread a different range of the vector to work with?

Comment: I can, but it is not efficient. As some threads may finish much faster than others. objects are different in terms of time to read.

Comment: Then split it up into smaller chunks and use a task-based approach. If a thread finishes with its task it starts on the next chunk. Perhaps using `std::async` or your own thread pool.

Comment: You probably need [Thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern)

Comment: You could synchronize a variable that holds the next available index and share that among all threads.  Then each thread gets the value of the variable and updates it by one when it goes to do its next read from the vector.

Comment: if your problem is that some objects can take longer to read than others, and because of that you don't want to do a simple split of the work by index (ex: thread 1 deal with 0 to 10, thread 2 deal with 11 to 20, etc...), why don't you pass full vector reference to every thread and work with a step equal to the threads count.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, what you are suggesting is the same. again, all threads end up reading equal  number of objects, which is not efficient.

Comment: Depending on what you are actually trying to do, a simple omp parallel for loop might do all you need.

Comment: OpenMP would fit very well here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting the input in equal parts is really really easy, it doesn't use locks and doesn't cause memory sharing. So try that, measure how much time each thread needs to complete and check if it's a relevant difference.

If the difference is relevant, consider using an array of one `atomic<bool>` per element, before reading an element, the thread does `compare_exchange_strong` on the flag related to that element (I think you can even use `memory_order_relaxed`, but use `memory_order_acq_rel` at first, only try relaxed if the performance doesn't satisfy you) and only actually processes the element if the exchange succeeds. Otherwise it tries with the next element, because someone is processing or has already processed the current one.

If you can't then you can use a single `atomic<int>` to store the index of the next element to be processed. The threads just use `fetch_add` or the postfix++ to atomically get the next element to process and increment the counter (the considerations for the memory ordering are the same as above). If the variance in reading times is high (as determined by step 1), you will have low contention on the atomic variable, so it will perform well.

If the contention is still too high, and you get a significant slowdown, try to estimate in advance how much time it will take to read an element. If you can, then sort your vector by estimated read time, and make the n-th thread read every n-th element, so that the load will be split more evenly.

Comment: In any case, don't use a lock, because you don't need it. On my pc, just incrementing an atomic variable on 500 threads is 5 times faster than incrementing a non-atomic variable guarded by a lock.